# Can I graft a Scion on a mature tree branch?

Tags: trees, apples, grafting, variety-selection, cultivar

Can I graft a scion on a different variety mature tree branch?

For example can I graft a [Kingston Black apple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingston_Black) scion on a [Dabinett apple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dabinett) tree branch?

Comment: Hello Andy Andy.   Can you please explain what a Kingston Black or a Cabinetry tree is?   Can you include the botanical name; Genus species and type of tree?  Are these fruit or nut trees? & What type of fruit or nut?

Comment: @GardenGems Malus domestica 'Kingston Black', Malus domestica 'Dabinett', they are apple trees

Comment: Yes you can graft many apple trees on one tree, but some will grow faster than others being more vigorous potentially over taking others.  But, I don't know enough about the art of grafting to answer your question fully.

Comment: The whole point of grafting is to combine different trees, so I would hazard a yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apples can be grafted onto mature trees. You'd obviously have to prune down the branch you are grafting onto, and make sure the scion is fitted to the living wood just beneath the bark, rather than in the middle of the cut.